# how to set unlimited request in API url | asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, api

I have a problem with an API:

```
{
    {
        "error-response": 
        { 
            "error-code": "TOO_MANY_REQUESTS",
            "error-message": "Request has been placed in time-out for exceeding quota or rate limits. Please reference HTTP header X-RateLimit-Reset for when requests can resubmitted."
        }
    }
}
```

I don't know how to set the rate limit to solve this problem.

This is my code

```
using (WebClient webClient = new WebClient())
{
    dataScou = webClient.DownloadString(API + Journal.ISSN);

    JObject rss = JObject.Parse(dataScou);

    Journal.citeScoreCurrentMetric = (double)rss["serial-metadata-response"]["entry"][0]["citeScoreYearInfoList"]["citeScoreCurrentMetric"];
    Journal.citeScoreCurrentMetricYear = (int)rss["serial-metadata-response"]["entry"][0]["citeScoreYearInfoList"]["citeScoreCurrentMetricYear"];

    if (rss["serial-metadata-response"]["entry"][0]["citeScoreYearInfoList"]["citeScoreTrackerYear"].ToString().Equals(null))
    {
        Journal.citeScoreTracker = "0";
        SaudiJournal.citeScoreTrackerYear = "0";
    }
    else
    {
        Journal.citeScoreTracker = (string)rss["serial-metadata-response"]["entry"][0]["citeScoreYearInfoList"]["citeScoreTracker"];
        Journal.citeScoreTrackerYear = (string)rss["serial-metadata-response"]["entry"][0]["citeScoreYearInfoList"]["citeScoreTrackerYear"];
    }
}
```

Comment: `IDK how set the rate limit to solve this problem.` Call it less often.

Comment: Your question is a bit like "how do I go through the 12 items or less lane at the supermarket with 50 items?". The answer is - you don't. :)